# How to set start and end time parameters using Vimeo player?

Tags: vimeo-player

For Youtube player I can set start and end time parameters which will crop video in this range. How can I do the same thing using Vimeo player?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- [Vimeo JavaScript API:](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) `seekTo(seconds:Number):void` and `pause():void` after some progress.
- [Vimeo ActionScript API:](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/as-api)
  `seek(seconds:Number):void` and `pause():void` after some progress.
- Also basic link parameter from [this Help Center article](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters): `vimeo.com/148198462#t=1m5s` Stopping the video at the particular time in this case isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using "setCurrentTime" for set the start of the video, and  'timeupdate' for set the end.

For the start of the video at a specific time:

```
Player.setCurrentTime(5);
```

The video will start after 5 seconds.

For the end of video:

```
video01Player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
  if (data.seconds > '10') {

    video01Player.pause();
 
  }
});
```

In this case the video will pause after 10 seconds.

**timeupdate**
This event fires when the playback position of the video changes, generally every 250 ms during playback, but the interval can vary depending on the browser.