# Load first 15 seconds of vimeo video

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have a webpage, where i only need to show the first 15 seconds of a video, inside a bootstrap modal box.
I have already made box load the video, but i need it, to only load 15 seconds?

I used this example to load the video:
http://jsfiddle.net/n90Lexgc/

```
$('.js-play').click(function(){

      var vid_num = $(this).data('vid');
      var vid_src = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+vid_num;
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', vid_src);
  })
```

Comment: I think for that you have to use vimeo api see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407215/vimeo-player-set-start-and-end-time-parameters-like-on-youtube

Comment: Thanks - i will try take a look at it, and return!

Answer (score 1):

This code will work:

```
player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
  if (data.seconds > 15) {

    player.pause().then(function(){
       video01Player.setCurrentTime(0);
    });
  }
});
```